# View broken path of Excel hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Editing a working hyperlink shows the destination worksheet selected and the destination cell. However, if that link breaks (eg Sheet name was changed), the Edit Hyperlink window no longer shows where it was pointing to. Where can that path be found?

Also, is it possible to get a path that you can work with? (Copy/Paste, Refer to in formula, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the path is shown in the "Screen Tip" of the cell with the hyperlink (hover cursor over cell until text pops up).
If this says something other than the path, then Edit the hyperlink, click on "ScreenTip..." and delete what's there → OK → OK. Now the path is displayed in the Screen Tip. 
Once satisfied, Undo to bring back the Screen Tip you just deleted.

As for a workable path, macros & UDFs are the only way that I found, such as in this article:
http://www.contextures.com/excelhyperlinkfunction.html